# Unrecognised name error in bq command line

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, command-line, google-bigquery, parameter-passing

I want to get the count of records of a table. I have written following procedure.

```
Create or replace procedure 
procedurename(In tablename string)
Begin
Declare sql1 string
Set sql1= 'select count(*) from ' ||tablename;
Execute immediate sql1;
End;
```

Questions :

1. When I am executing it in bq console using invoke sp, it's giving me count.
   But when I am executing it in bq command line using
   bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'call procedurename (tablename)'
   it's giving me error as 'unrecognized name : tablename'. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Sure. Done:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. You are getting `Unrecognized name:'tablename'` error because in your query `tablename` is not defined.

Try using the following command to execute your stored procedure

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
‘DECLARE tablename STRING DEFAULT NULL;
set tablename="your-table-name";
CALL `projectid.datasetid.procedurename`(tablename);’
```

2. To pass the tablename as parameter, you can try using bq command line or client libraries as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries).

For example in bq command line:

```
    bq query \
    --use_legacy_sql=false \
    --parameter=tablename:string:your-table-name \
    'DECLARE tablename STRING ;
    CALL `projectid.datasetid.procedurename`(@tablename);'
```

Answer to comment#1:

- Passing a user input at runtime is not possible using the bq command line but, you can use client library instead to pass the table name at runtime.

For example refer to this python script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client(project="project_id")

mytable1=raw_input("Enter your table: ")

query = """
   DECLARE tablename STRING ;
   CALL `project_id.dataset.procFedurename`(@tablename);

"""
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
   query_parameters=[
       bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("tablename", "STRING", mytable1),
      
   ]
)

job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.

for row in job.result():
   print("No of records:{}".format(row[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also tell me if there is a way to print a statement using this SP where it will ask me at runtime to type the name of the table and after giving the name it will give me the result?

Comment: Hi I tried the above command in bq command line but I am still getting the error as 'Unrecognized name'.

Comment: Hi @Kavya14, I have edited my answer for comment#1.

Comment: I was able to get the result successfully using the above command. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co6s5.png). Please check if you’re using the command correctly. If the issue persists, share your full error along with the command.